# Convert Gridview rows to Columns in ASP.NET C #

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, transpose

I am working with asp.net c# and SQL. I've bound my `GridView` to an XML File and data displayed like image 1 below. Can someone make a suggestion as to how I could modify my code to get my data display as in image 2? 
[image: Image of the output i have]
[image: Image of the output i want]

Here is my code

```
   protected void RotateandBind()
   {

    XmlReader myxmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:/stgt.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet dss = new DataSet();
    dss.ReadXml(myxmlFile);
    GridView1.DataSource = dss.Tables["Attribute"];
    DataTable dtbefore = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataTable dtafter = new DataTable();


    for (int i = 0; i <= dtbefore.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        dtafter.Columns.Add("");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < dtbefore.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtafter.NewRow();

        dr[0] = dtbefore.Columns[k].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < dtbefore.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
           dr[j + 1] = dtbefore.Rows[j][k].ToString();
        }
        dtafter.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


  }
```

Comment: Any SQL language involved?

Comment: Yes i'will write a stored procedure in sql and invoke it in my Csharp code

Comment: The task you are trying to achieve is called Pivoting. You can see this link. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/   
Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. It gets the first row, converts it the the column headers and then deletes the first row which contained the column headers.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dtafter.Columns)
{
 string cName = dtafter.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
if (!table.Columns.Contains(cName) && cName != "")
{
     column.ColumnName = cName;
}

}

dtafter.Rows[0].Delete(); //If you don't need that row any more
```